# Is this an attempt at fraud/impersonation? stockoverflows.com

Tags: discussion, security, clone, copyright-infringement

I just stumbled upon [stockoverflows.com](http://stockoverflows.com), which seems to be an attempt to impersonate the Stack Overflow website.

Should something be done about this? At first thought, I'm concerned about the possible attempt to steal login credentials. At the very least, there's a copyright infringement issue — of the site design and logo, if not of the CC content.

For what it's worth, the domain registrar is hiding behind whois privacy:

```
Domain Name: stockoverflows.com
Registry Domain ID: 1927798280_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.namesilo.com
Registrar URL: https://www.namesilo.com/
Updated Date: 2016-03-28
Creation Date: 2015-05-11
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2016-05-11
Registrar: NameSilo, LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 1479
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: 
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6024928198
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: Domain Administrator
Registrant Organization: See PrivacyGuardian.org
Registrant Street: 1928 E. Highland Ave. Ste F104 PMB# 255
Registrant City: Phoenix
Registrant State/Province: AZ
Registrant Postal Code: 85016
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.3478717726
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: 
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: pw-39ff5aac5e30e92abbca1d2b54f52045@privacyguardian.org
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: Domain Administrator
Admin Organization: See PrivacyGuardian.org
Admin Street: 1928 E. Highland Ave. Ste F104 PMB# 255
Admin City: Phoenix
Admin State/Province: AZ
Admin Postal Code: 85016
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.3478717726
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: 
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: pw-39ff5aac5e30e92abbca1d2b54f52045@privacyguardian.org
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: Domain Administrator
Tech Organization: See PrivacyGuardian.org
Tech Street: 1928 E. Highland Ave. Ste F104 PMB# 255
Tech City: Phoenix
Tech State/Province: AZ
Tech Postal Code: 85016
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.3478717726
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: 
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: pw-39ff5aac5e30e92abbca1d2b54f52045@privacyguardian.org
Name Server: PNS11.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS12.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS13.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS14.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS15.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS16.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS17.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS18.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS19.CLOUDNS.NET
Name Server: PNS20.CLOUDNS.NET
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/

Domains - cheap, easy, and secure at NameSilo.com

http://www.namesilo.com
```

Comment: this seem more a (somehow poor) phishing attempt rather than mere scrapping. I actually would like to have a public pinned list of such attempts that users can feed into blacklisting.